# Modify Returns of existing Setup

Tags: moq

Let's say I have a standard setup that looks something like this:

`mock.Setup(myObj => myObj.MyMethod(It.Is<MyT>(item => IsTrue(item)))).Returns(someList)`

Is it possible in a separate line of code to identify the exact same `Setup` (mocking the same method with the same `It.Is` criteria), and then modify the `Returns`?  For example, suppose under one condition I want `MyMethod` to return the list {0,1,2} and then later I determine that under the same condition I also want to return {3,4,5}.  Because of the way the code is structured, I don't know about the {3,4,5} a priori so I cannot use it with the initial setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
var someList = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, };
mock.Setup(myObj => myObj.MyMethod(It.Is<MyT>(item => IsTrue(item))))
  .Returns(someList);

// use 'mock' first time(s)

someList.Clear();  // if wanted
someList.AddRange(new[] { 3, 4, 5, });

// use 'mock' additional time(s)
```

This works because `List<>` is a reference type. Moq just remembers a reference to where the `List<>` object is. If you mutate the `List<>` object (without changing the reference to a `new List<int>`!), that is fine.

On the other hand, if you want to change the reference to a distinct object (another instance), use a lambda (almost like in Spritely's answer):

```
var someList = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, };
mock.Setup(myObj => myObj.MyMethod(It.Is<MyT>(item => IsTrue(item))))
  .Returns(() => someList);

// use 'mock' first time(s)

someList = new List<int> { 3, 4, 5, };

// use 'mock' additional time(s)
```

In my second solution, observe the arrow **`() => someList`**.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a delegate to Returns like this:

```
mock.Setup(myObj => myObj.MyMethod(It.Is<MyT>(item => IsTrue(item)))).Returns(item => (condition) ? list1 : list2)
```